# SQL Error (Missing Operator) In query operation error

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, syntax-error, rdbms

I am building an application and using MS Access as database(Normally I don't use MS Access but the client needs service-less database). Anyways, I have multiple tables and using joins, I am trying to acquire output, here is the query

```
SELECT tblSalesDetail.Sales_Details_ID, tblProduct.Product_Name, 
       tblSalesDetail.Rate, tblSalesDetail.Quantity, tblSalesDetail.TaxableAmount, 
       tblSalesDetail.TaxableAmount + tblSalesDetail.CGST_Amt + 
       tblSalesDetail.SGST_Amt + tblSalesDetail.IGST_Amt AS TotalAmt 
FROM tblSalesMain 
INNER JOIN tblSalesDetail 
   ON tblSalesMain.Sales_Main_ID = tblSalesDetail.Sales_Main_ID 
INNER JOIN tblProduct 
   ON tblSalesDetail.Product_ID = tblProduct.Product_ID 
WHERE tblSalesMain.Sales_Main_ID=1
```

This query works perfectly in SQL Server but having the following error when trying to run in MS Access with text selected at `_Name` at `tblProduct.Product_Name` in the first line.

[image]

I tried by changing or removing that column, but it's not working.

I tried StackOverflow answers posted but none of them worked by the way. So it's not like I am directly posting a question here without trying to solve this.

I know this might be a simple problem but I am stuck. Let me know workaround this.

I know this is off the above topic but can anyone suggest me good service-less, localdb (not mdf based SQL Db) for visual studio?

Regards

Comment: . . There are other serverless databases you can choose.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Well, suggesting a good one will solve above I hope. Anyone good DB you can suggest?

Comment: @Andre Looks like it. It's bad I couldn't find that earlier. Thanks for notifying though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS Access is quite finicky about syntax.  Try this:

```
SELECT tblSalesDetail.Sales_Details_ID, tblProduct.Product_Name, tblSalesDetail.Rate, 
       tblSalesDetail.Quantity, tblSalesDetail.TaxableAmount,
       (tblSalesDetail.TaxableAmount + tblSalesDetail.CGST_Amt + tblSalesDetail.SGST_Amt + tblSalesDetail.IGST_Amt) AS TotalAmt
FROM (tblSalesMain INNER JOIN
      tblSalesDetail
      ON tblSalesMain.Sales_Main_ID = tblSalesDetail.Sales_Main_ID
     ) INNER JOIN
     tblProduct
     ON tblSalesDetail.Product_ID = tblProduct.Product_ID WHERE tblSalesMain.Sales_Main_ID = 1
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked but what was the problem and what have you changed. I know I can compare both queries but asking for the sake of explanation and other developers. Please elaborate on the answer

Comment: @Mahadev ... See above linked duplicate. MS Access SQL requires parentheses pairing for queries with more than one `JOIN`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, about that *finicky* syntax, please see, share, vote, or comment on my recent [ticket](https://access.uservoice.com/forums/319956-access-desktop-application/suggestions/37193662-upgrade-access-sql-dialect-to-current-ansi-standar) to the Access team to upgrade its dialect to current standards of which includes this parenthesis requirement that frustrate new users.

Comment: @Parfait: Got it. And voted on your ticket.

Comment: @Parfait . . . Fortunately, there are many choices of database out there that *do* support more standard SQL syntax and functionality.